# One class common in few projects

Tags: java, shared-libraries, microservices

I am building a microservice application and I have one class common for four modules(separate projects). Can I do sth about it (to not duplicate it in four projects)?. It's only one class, but it's for authentication so I don't want somebody to change it by mistake. Is it possible to do a one class library or it's a bad idea?

Comment: Can you share how are you implementing your microservice architecture? For example, are you using third-party solutions for a serverless approach?

Comment: Pack it into a library and include it in all projects. This can easily be done using dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. Like mentioned in the comments, "pack it into a library and include it in all projects" by using your dependency management. It's not a bad idea, though if the class is very simple, it might not be worth the effort.

Since you're going with microservices, you could also change your architecture in a way that your authentication is a service in its own right, which other microservices use. Authentication usually isn't duplicated into all projects: there is a separate authentication service and different microservices either just check that authentication has already been done and has the permissions needed or call the authentication service when required.

Comment: Actually, the class is about 54 lines with imports so it's not long. When it comes to one authentication module which other modules call I think it's not a good solution and I also have read it in several articles. When you have one authentication module, then all of other modules have to call it every time user calls a service which needs authentication. It really slows things down and complicates it unnecessarily. I use JWT tokens and I do not need any other module or database in my module to check if user is authenticated:)